# redraw google charts on hidden bootstrap tab pane

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I am using google scatter chart in my web app and it loads on document ready. I recently did some restructuring and trying to divide the page content in different bootstrap tabs.

If I load the graph on the active tab pane it work fine and the width, height parameters of the graph is correct. However if I shift the graph to a hidden tab the graph doesn't load properly with the parameters passed on the function (specially width and height). At the moment I am calling the graph on document ready.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="layout layout-stack-sm layout-main-right">
    <div class="col-sm-3 layout-sidebar">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-layout-sidebar nav-stacked">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#quick-stats" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Quick Stats
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#engagement-graph" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Engagement graph
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- layout sidebar -->

    <div class="col-sm-9 layout-main">
        <div class="tab-content stacked-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="quick-stats">
                Some content   
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="engagement-graph">
                <div id="myMoodPage">
                <div class="graph" id="graph">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Loading graph on document ready

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myMoodPage').myMood({
            graphDataUrl: '<?php echo $this->url('my_mood/mood_graph_data'); ?>',
            graphData: <?php echo $graphData; ?>,
            titles: ['<?php echo $this->translate('time'); ?>', '<?php echo $this->translate('mood'); ?>', '<?php echo $this->translate('avg'); ?>']
        });
    });

    function updatePageCharts() {
        $('#myMoodPage').myMood('loadGraph');
    }

    $("a[href='#engagement-graph']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            packages: ['corechart'],
            callback: drawChart
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my main JS file where I am defining the graph parameters and other things (which are not actually relevant for this question, but just for the sake of completeness I am posting the whole function)

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.myMood", {
        options: {
            graphDataUrl: "",
            graphData: {},
            titles: ["time", "mood", "avg"]
        },
        _create: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.periodSelect = this.element.find('select[name="period"]');
            this.questionSelect = this.element.find('select[name="question"]');
            this.graphContainer = this.element.find(".statistics");
            this.atStart = this.element.find("#atStart .value");
            this.highest = this.element.find("#highest .value");
            this.lowest = this.element.find("#lowest .value");
            this.current = this.element.find("#current .value");
            this.last30 = this.element.find("#last30 .value");
            this.last30Trend = this.element.find("#last30");
            this.week = this.element.find("#week .value");
            this.weekTrend = this.element.find("#week");
            this.graphId = "graph";
            this.selectedFilterName = this.options.titles[2];
            this.periodSelect.change(function () {
                self.loadGraph()
            });
            this.questionSelect.change(function () {
                self.loadGraph();
                self.selectedFilterName = self.questionSelect.find("option:selected").text()
            });
            this.setGraphData(this.options.graphData);
            return this
        },
        loadGraph: function () {
            var self = this;
            var data = {
                period: self.periodSelect.val(),
                question: self.questionSelect.val()
            };
            var success = function (data) {
                self.setGraphData(data)
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: self.options.graphDataUrl,
                data: data,
                success: success
            })
        },
        setGraphData: function (data) {
            var self = this;
            this.atStart.text(data.atStart);
            this.highest.text(data.highest);
            this.lowest.text(data.lowest);
            this.current.text(data.current);
            this.last30.text(data.last30.val);
            this.last30Trend.find(".up, .down").hide();
            this.last30Trend.removeClass("incr");
            this.last30Trend.removeClass("decr");
            if (Number(data.last30.trend) > 0) {
                this.last30Trend.find(".up").show();
                this.last30Trend.addClass("incr")
            }
            if (Number(data.last30.trend) < 0) {
                this.last30Trend.find(".down").show();
                this.last30Trend.addClass("decr")
            }
            this.week.text(data.week.val);
            this.weekTrend.find(".up, .down").hide();
            this.weekTrend.removeClass("incr");
            this.weekTrend.removeClass("decr");
            if (Number(data.week.trend) > 0) {
                this.weekTrend.find(".up").show();
                this.weekTrend.addClass("incr")
            }
            if (Number(data.week.trend) < 0) {
                this.weekTrend.find(".down").show();
                this.weekTrend.addClass("decr")
            }
            var moodData = data.mood;
            var dataArray = new Array();
            for (i in moodData) {
                if (moodData[i].avg == null) {
                    moodData[i].avg = undefined
                }
                if (moodData[i].mood == null) {
                    moodData[i].mood = undefined
                }
                if (moodData[i].team == null) {
                    moodData[i].team = undefined
                }
                var moodText = '<div style="border-radius: 2px; padding: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; background-color: #9c3b8a;">';
                if (moodData[i].event != null) {
                    moodText += moodData[i].event + " "
                }
                moodText += moodData[i].mood;
                if (moodData[i].comment) {
                    moodText += "<br>" + moodData[i].comment
                }
                moodText += "</div>";
                var avgText = '<div style="border-radius: 2px; padding: 10px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; background-color: #15426c;">';
                if (moodData[i].event != null) {
                    avgText += moodData[i].event + " "
                }
                avgText += moodData[i].avg;
                if (moodData[i].publicComment) {
                    avgText += "<br>" + moodData[i].publicComment
                }
                avgText += "</div>";
                var row = [new Date(moodData[i].time * 1000), Number(moodData[i].mood), moodText, Number(moodData[i].avg), avgText, false];
                dataArray.push(row)
            }
            if (google) {
                drawChart()
            } else {
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)
            }

            function drawChart() {
                var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dataTable.addColumn("date", self.options.titles[0]);
                dataTable.addColumn("number", self.options.titles[1]);
                dataTable.addColumn({
                    type: "string",
                    role: "tooltip",
                    p: {
                        html: true
                    }
                });
                dataTable.addColumn("number", self.selectedFilterName);
                dataTable.addColumn({
                    type: "string",
                    role: "tooltip",
                    p: {
                        html: true
                    }
                });
                dataTable.addColumn({
                    type: "boolean",
                    role: "certainty"
                });
                dataTable.addRows(dataArray);
                var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
                var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById(self.graphId));
                var options = {
                    legend: {
                        position: "bottom"
                    },
                    interpolateNulls: true,
                    chartArea: {
                        left: 25,
                        top: 25,
                        width: '92%',
                        height: '80%'
                    },
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                    vAxis: {
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 6,
                        viewWindow: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 6
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        isHtml: true
                    },
                    series: {
                        0: {
                            color: "#9c3b8a",
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            pointSize: 6
                        },
                        1: {
                            color: "#15426c",
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            pointSize: 3
                        }
                    }
                };
                chart.draw(dataView, options)
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

I tried reloading the graph like this, but it didn't work

```
$("a[href='#engagement-graph']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            packages: ['corechart'],
            callback: drawChart
        });
    });
```

Screenshot in 2 different situation

Loading on active tab pane
[image]

Loading on hidden tab pane
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Drawing charts inside hidden divs (which is usually what tab interfaces are implemented as) breaks the dimension detection algorithms in the Visualization API, which is why the chart draws oddly when drawn in any tab other than the tab open at the start.

You can load the API only once; subsequent calls to `google.load` for the Visualization API will be ignored, which is why your "shown.bs.tab" event handler does not do what you want.

Since delaying the tab initialization until after the charts draw is not really a viable option with Bootstrap, I would suggest replacing this code:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});

$("a[href='#engagement-graph']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart'],
        callback: drawChart
    });
});
```

with this:

```
function init () {
    if (/* boolean expression teting if chart tab is open */) {
        drawChart();
    }
    else {
        $("a[href='#engagement-graph']").one('shown.bs.tab', drawChart);
    }
}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback: init});
```

This should draw the chart if its container tab is open, and create a one-time event handler that draws the chart the first time the tab is opened if the tab is not open.

You need to put this code inside the `setGraphData` function to avoid a race condition with your data loading, and so the `drawChart` function will be in scope.  Also, remove these lines:

```
if (google) {
    drawChart()
} else {
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)
}
```

The `google` object exists as soon as the script tag for the `jsapi` loads, which will be before this code is executed, so you will always trigger the `drawChart` function here.  Having the `google` object available, however, does not mean that the Visualization API is loaded.

Comment: thanks for you details response. Can you please tell me what boolean value should I use inside if () condition. If I use 'true' the problem still persist. If I use 'false' graph dimension is loaded properly inside hidden tab, but when I interact with the graph (e.g. changing time and other inputs  - as you can see in my function), nothing happens and the graph is not rendered at all if I change the time period from drop down menu (i.e - only showing last month data)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the way bootstrap tabs work to say what that boolean expression should be.

Comment: I voted up for your detailed answer. However, I can't accept it as a solution since it didn't solve my problem. But still your response might be very helpful in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

Just incase other people are looking for a simpler solution.

An alternative is to implement the following:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var ev = document.createEvent('Event');
    ev.initEvent('resize', true, true);
    window.dispatchEvent(ev);
  });
```

This will cause the chart to re-draw as if the browser was resized.

Comment: Thanks @TikiBoy is really simple and worked perfectly for me. I advise someone with this problem, use this solution from our ae friend. hug