# Resizable Google Visualization inside JQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Inside of a JQuery resizable `div` I have a JQuery Accordion Widget. Inside of each accordion element is a `table` that is centered in the accordion `div` by setting `width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;`. In each table is a `td` element that has a Google Visualization Column Chart.

When the resize event is triggered I'd like the Google Visualizations to redraw so the dimensions of the Charts fit the new container sizes. The problem I'm having is that the only Chart that is redrawn with the proper dimensions is the one in the visible accordion div.

I'm assuming that when a `div` element is set to `display=none` the container dimensions are ignored in the resize event. If this is true does anyone have any good suggestions to work around this?

I should also add that the width of the visualization is set to '100%' not a pixel number.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. Is the chart inside a raw td or have you tried to put it in a div at 100% height and width? How many td's are in the table? If few, why a table? And have you tried styling with area, height width?

Comment: it's in a div. And honestly the reason it's in a table is because my css skills are weak. the entire table consists of 3 rows with 3 td elements in each row. row 1 == header. row 2 == input box, range slider, input box. row 3 == '', chart, ''.  The chart is to show the distribution of items relating to the position of the above slider.

Comment: Well, sometimes tables can be a bit restrictive, so here's a fiddle with all divs, and maybe we can spiff that up a bit...http://jsfiddle.net/FT2qC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set explicity dimensions in in your chart.draw() call since you're drawing a chart on a hidden element.  So for your options variable you would set it to:

```
var options = {'width':400,
               'height':300}; //substitute your desired dimensions
chart.draw(data, options);
```

*Adjust accordingly if you're using one of the other Google Charts draw methods (wrapper.Draw() or drawChart()).*

From another recent similar question, the Google Charts API pulls the dimensions from the container element when the draw call is made, but if the container is hidden, it has nothing to pull from.

related: [redraw google charts on hidden bootstrap tab pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932363/redraw-google-charts-on-hidden-bootstrap-tab-pane)

Comment: Thank you GVIrish. This is more or less inline with my assumptions. The % value in my chart options was the problem.